# Show play timing, remaining time of play

Tags: android, seekbar

I use the following code to play the recorded audio file, it works fine. I have a seekbar which shows the progress of the play. I have two static text called start and end. I need to show the duration of the play (00.00 to max duration) in the start text and decrement the time from max duration to 00.00. I need to show the progressing time, remaining time... Any suggestion..

```
private void playAudio() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        end.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text1 = "Your audio will play";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(context, text1, duration);
        toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast1.show();
```

`String newFolderName = "/ComAudioRecorder";
    String extstoredir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .toString();
    String filename = "/combinedrecaudio.wav";
    String path1 = extstoredir + newFolderName + filename;
    Log.d("path1", path1);
    /*
     * String path=path2; Log.d("path",path);
     */
     mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(path1);
        mPlayer.prepare();          
        mPlayer.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mSeekBar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (mPlayer != null
                    && mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() < mPlayer.getDuration()) {
                Log.d("Indide Run Method",Integer.toString(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mSeekBar.setProgress(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
      start.setText(Long.toString(startTime));              
                //end.setText(Double.toString());
            }           
        }

    }).start();
     pos=mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    mSeekBar.setProgress(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    // mPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    pauseRecord.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    resumeRec.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    /*start.setText(Double.toString(starttext));
    starttext=starttext+00.01;*/
    // start.setText((int) (mPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/100000.0));
    // end.setText(currentTime);

    // start.setText();
    // mDelete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cann't update the UI in the thread.you can post them to Runnable.

in the run method() put the following code.

```
mHandler.post(updateUI);
```

then use handler to update the ui

```
 private final Runnable updateUI= new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {
                    //update ur ui here     
                      start.setText((mPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/mPlayer.getDuration())*100); ‌​ end.setText(mPlayer.getDuration()-mPlayer.getCurrentPosition())

                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

Answer (score 3):

for every 1 second you can update the progress bar with the formula `(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/mPlayer.getDuration)*100;`

similarly you can get the remaining time by using **`mPlayer.getDuration-mPlayer.getCurrentPosition()`;**

you can get the getDuration() of your audio file at the onPreparedListener...

got success let me know.

Comment: I used this shows error public void run() {    
 while (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() < mPlayer.getDuration()) { Log.d("Indide Run Method",Integer.toString(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
     try {
      Thread.sleep(100);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     mSeekBar.setProgress(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
     start.setText((mPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/mPlayer.getDuration())*100);    
           end.setText(mPlayer.getDuration()-mPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    }   
   }

  }).start();

Comment: where should I place these inside the thread or out of the thread.. could you pls update the answer related to my code.

Comment: Thanks, It works. But the start text wont get updated as the seekbar moves. Shows 0 only. At the end of the play start text change to 100 always, even the play time is more..

Comment: what do u want to display in the start text?

Comment: In the start text I need to display the progress of the play from 00.00 to the duration of the play.. it has to increase.

Comment: Hi,, I got it. In start text only mPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), not (mPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/mPlayer.getDuration())*100. thanks for your answer...